# Chess Clock using Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am creating a two-player chess app (with ability to host multiple games at same time) using `chess.js` and `chessboard.js` libraries and using it over Socket.IO, Express and Node.JS.

Chess works fine but not the timer. I have decided to setup the clocks on server rather than on client (because of performance issues - i.e setInterval never matches on two computers).

I am able to setup clocks for only one game though. The reason being, when a new game starts, the clearInterval function of one game, overrides the other. How do I setup multiple instances of clocks on the server while still be able to clear them out as and when required? Here is the code that is working but only for one game (i.e two clocks). If I introduce one more game on this, the clocks run crazy.

Server-side code:

```
 socket.on('client-timer', function(cltmr) {

    var client_white_timer = cltmr.timer_white;
    var client_black_timer = cltmr.timer_black;
    var client_sent_now_playing = cltmr.now_playing;
    var client_sent_gameId = cltmr.gameId;
    var client_sent_gamestart = cltmr.gamestart;
    var emitterid = "server-timer-"+client_sent_gameId;

     if (client_sent_now_playing === 'w' || client_sent_gamestart == 1) {
        w_setInterval = setInterval(function() {
                client_white_timer--;
                io.emit(emitterid,{countdown_white: client_white_timer, countdown_black: client_black_timer});
        }, 1000);            
    }


    if (client_sent_now_playing === 'b') {
        b_setInterval = setInterval(function() {
                client_black_timer--;
                io.emit(emitterid,{countdown_white: client_white_timer, countdown_black: client_black_timer});
        }, 1000);            
    } 

});

socket.on('clear-timers', function(clr){
    var clrw = clr.wclr;
    var clrb = clr.bclr;
    clearInterval(w_setInterval);
    clearInterval(b_setInterval);

})
```

Client-side code:

```
      var onChange = function(oldPos, newPos) {

        var whiteseconds = splitseconds("new-w-timer");
        var blackseconds = splitseconds("new-b-timer");
        //console.log(username,whiteplayerid, blackplayerid);
      var emitRecieverid = "server-timer-"+serverGame.id;

      if (username == whiteplayerid) {
            if (game.turn() == 'b') {

        socket.emit('clear-timers', {clrw: serverGame.id+1, clrb: serverGame.id+2});

                socket.emit('client-timer', {gameId: serverGame.id, playeremitted: username, timer_white: whiteseconds, timer_black: blackseconds, now_playing: 'b', gameover: game.game_over(), gamestart: 0 });
            }

            else {
        socket.emit('clear-timers', {clrw: serverGame.id+1, clrb: serverGame.id+2});

                socket.emit('client-timer', {gameId: serverGame.id, playeremitted: username, timer_white: whiteseconds, timer_black: blackseconds, now_playing: 'w', gameover: game.game_over(), gamestart: 0 });

            }

    }

        socket.on(emitRecieverid, function(timermsg){
            //console.log(timermsg); 
            $('#new-w-timer').html(sec_to_time(timermsg.countdown_white));
            $('#new-b-timer').html(sec_to_time(timermsg.countdown_black));
        }); 

  }
```

Comment: `socket` are objects. You can add keys to them, so you can store counters, intervals, etc. in each socket object. `socket.myInterval = setInterval(...)` so each interval will be socket-dependent.

Comment: @JeremyThille Interesting! Very useful tip. So is it possible to assign unique setInterval for each game separately? How do I access them on the client side? and How do I clear them if I want to pause and restart with new values? More help on this will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Well you can't access the interval client-side, because it's attached to the server-side socket. But you can send instructions to the server to stop or restart the socket's interval. Anyway, you can always communicate both ways, that's the point of sockets.

Comment: can anybody help me .how to create chess clock in server side???

Comment: did you ever figure this out , very difficult in my opinion but must be possible as chess.com has it working and i'm sure there are 10,000 games playing on there at any one time